# Angular category sorting not working as per category names

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to achieve category sorting in Angular js but its not working properly. It pulls data from desciption as well. I want to restrict it to categories names but no luck.

JS code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.factory('Items', ['$http', function($http){
  return {
    get: function(callback){
      $http.get('items.json').success(function(data){
        callback(data);
      })
    }
  }
}]);

myApp.factory('Categories', ['$http', function($http){
  return {
    get: function(callback){
      $http.get('categories.json').success(function(data){
        callback(data);
      })
    }
  }
}]);

// Config and Routes 
myApp.config(function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
                templateUrl:"home.html"
        })
        .when('/item/:id', {
                templateUrl:"item.html"
        })
})

myApp.controller('headerController', function($scope, $location) {
  $scope.goHome = function () {
    $location.path('/');
  };
})



function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.greeting = 'hello';
}

// Controllers
myApp.controller('ItemController', function($scope, $route, $location, $http, Items){

  Items.get(function(response){
    $scope.items = response;
  });

  // Update this value dynamically - onclick
  $scope.filters = "food";

  $scope.viewDetail = function(item) {
        $location.path('/item/' + item.id);
    }

})  


myApp.controller('ListController', function($scope, $route, $location, $http, Categories){

  $scope.sendCategory = function(category) {
    // How can I pass this value to ItemController?
     $scope.search =category.name;
  };

   $scope.orderProp='date';

    $scope.tab = function (tabIndex) {
     //Sort by date
      if (tabIndex == 1){
        //alert(tabIndex);
        $scope.orderProp='date';

      }   
      //Sort by views 
      if (tabIndex == 2){
        $scope.orderProp = 'views';
      }

   };

   $scope.sort = function(item) {
       if (  $scope.orderProp == 'date') {
            return new Date(item.date);
        }
        return item[$scope.orderProp];
   }

})  


myApp.controller('CategoryController', function($scope, $route, $location, $http, Categories){

  Categories.get(function(response){
    $scope.categories = response;
  });


})  

myApp.controller("tabsController", function ($scope) {

   $scope.orderProp = 'date';

})

myApp.controller('ItemDetailController', function($scope, $route, $location, $http, Items){
    Items.get(function(response){
    $scope.items = response; 

    if ($route.current.params.id) {
      angular.forEach($scope.items, function (v, k) {
        if (v.id == $route.current.params.id) {
          $scope.currItem = $scope.items[k];
          return false;
        }
      });
    }
  });
})
```

can any one please help to find the way I can sort the data only as per my category names instead searching data on the overall pages?

Sharing the reference URL I found for this.

http://plnkr.co/edit/rh3wGYhuoHSHJEa4PoQi?p=preview

It would be great help if any can help me out.

Comment: Could you provide the html as well? since I'm guessing you're using an angular filter to achieve this.

Comment: here is the working example... http://plnkr.co/edit/rh3wGYhuoHSHJEa4PoQi?p=preview

Comment: Just as an aside, your Items service is just a restrictive wrapper around $http. Instead, why not create a constant for the 'items.json' path and use $http directly? That way, you can make use of all of the Promise functions (ie add an error handler, or a finally() callback)...

Comment: Hi Shaun, if you could edit my example URL will help me a lot. I am not sure about your guidance. Thanks for the time.